# Choosing samples that maximise coverage of a biological gradient

Tags: r, loops

I have several tanks covering a gradient in salinity (please see attached file; unit arbitrary). My task is to select 15 tanks that cover the gradient best. However, some salinity ranges are overrepresented in the data. Thus, there is the chance that these salinity windows will be overrepresented if I choose tanks in a regular manner. Is there a possibility to correct for that using the programming language R?
If there is an dedicated R package for doing that job, that would be very helpful as well.

[image: Gradient_salinity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, I've had to recreate your data the hard way, and it won't be exact:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Tank, Salinity)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

If you want to get an approximately even coverage of the salinity, all you need to do is work out what an ideal optimum coverage of the range over 15 tanks would look like. In other words, you split your range equally between the minimum and maximum range, and find out where the ideal salinity of your 15 tanks would be:

```
optima  <- seq(min(df$Salinity), max(df$Salinity), length.out = 15)
```

Now all you need to do is find the closest tank to each of these optima:

```
optimal <- sapply(optima, function(i) which.min(abs(df$Salinity - i)))
```

So now if we plot just these 15 tanks, we will see we get a much more linear coverage of the salinity:

```
ggplot(df[optimal, ], aes(Tank, Salinity)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- structure(list(Tank = structure(1:35, .Label = c("24", "23", 
"33", "2", "18", "11", "35", "34", "20", "5", "16", "10", "31", 
"22", "13", "30", "9", "7", "28", "29", "21", "15", "32", "14", 
"8", "6", "12", "17", "4", "27", "26", "1", "25", "19", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    Salinity = c(0.18, 0.4, 0.45, 0.52, 0.57, 0.62, 0.7, 0.75, 
    0.76, 0.78, 0.79, 0.81, 0.84, 0.86, 0.9, 0.91, 0.99, 1.01, 
    1.02, 1.04, 1.1, 1.2, 1.25, 1.26, 1.3, 1.31, 1.4, 1.45, 1.65, 
    1.78, 1.85, 1.87, 1.88, 2.2, 2.25)), row.names = c(NA, -35L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Simply perfect. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: However, the "optima" values are sometimes so close together that the same tank is being selected multiple times. In the end, this results in fewer than 15 tanks having been selected. :(